# Git push throws error

Tags: git

What does this mean and what do I need to do to come out of this error

[image]

I am in local develop branch and changed some files in local working directory and then I added those changed file via git add and after then I was to able to commit those modified file using git commit , but I am getting the above error while doing git push

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's written right there: "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally".

In other words, the remote branch has been updated with contents, and you trying to push your local commits to the remote branch would cause the updated contents on the remote branch to be overwritten, and git would not allow that.

Just pull the latest updates using `git pull origin` and try the whole proccess again.

HINT: Don't forget to backup your current local branch before pulling.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to pull the updated changes from the Repository(Git/SVN). ThenAfter try to push your changes to the Repository

Comment: if I apply git pull then does it overwrite all my existing changes in my local?

Comment: Your local changes won't effect with the pull request.But you may get conflicts  . If you that doubt make local back up and pull changes.

Comment: ok Thanks . I will take the backup for safer and apply git pull origin develop

Comment: Cool. Good luck